# Run DeepExplainer on time-series data takes forever

Tags: tensorflow, shap

I have a tensorflow time-series classification model with multiple LSTM layers.

The input has the shape (None, 80, 6)  (i.e 6 features with 80 samples).

The output has the shape (None,  40) (i.e 40 classes).

I'm using tensorflow 2.4 and shap version 0.41.0

I'm trying to use `DeepExplainer` but it seems to run and never ends !

I have a `train_subset` (240, 80, 6) and `single_input` (1, 80, 6);

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()
import shap
```

```
devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices("GPU")
for device in devices:
   tf.config.experimental set_memory_growth(device, True)
   tf.config.set_visible_devices(device, "GPU")
```

```
explainer = shap.DeepExplainer(model, train_subset)
shap_values = explainer .shap_values(single_input )
```

it run for more than 8 hours...

What can I do in order to use the shap with my model ?